# Where is the DefaultIfEmpty with the linq query style

Tags: c#, linq

```
var query = from r in list where r.Id == "" DefaultIfEmpty(String.Empty)
```

does not work.

How do I have to write a linq query with query style and use the  DefaultIfEmpty method?

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is not a good explanation about your problem. What is your `list `?

Comment: "does not work." is not a compiler error, is it? Looking at compiler errors could help fixing such problems by yourself

Comment: It seems I just missed the braces () around the query to make intellisense working thats stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your list contains the type `Item` you would want:

```
// define your default item
var defaultItem = new Item { ... };

var query = (from r in list where r.Id == "" select r).DefaultIfEmpty(defaultItem);
```

or in method syntax

```
var query = list.Where( r => r.Id == "" ).DefaultIfEmpty(defaultItem);
```

However if you're selecting a specific string property of `Item` then you may want something like

```
var query = (from r in list where r.Id == "" select r.StringProperty)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty);
```

Comment: This particular question shows how ugly query syntax can be. +1 for method syntax, I personally think that query syntax is here for those who come with SQL background and simply do not understand C#.

Comment: @KenKin I'm saying what I'm saying, nothing more. Query syntax can be useful with some complex joins, otherwise method syntax looks cleaner and readable. Also, in VB query syntax looks less verbose and even nicer than method syntax + fact that people with SQL background can easily understand it = reason it's here in C# and VB.

Comment: @taras.roshko: Then I delete it.

Answer (score 1):

[DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty.aspx) is used *usually* with `JOINS`, (outer joins). 
You may see: [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx)

For your case it apears you want to select empty string if the r.Id is null, you can you can do:

```
var query = from r in list
            select new 
               {
                 ID =  r.Id == null ? string.Empty : r.Id
               };
```

Comment: @KenKin, thanks edited my answer, you can always go and edit the answer if you think the edit can improve it